# What Different Patterns Are There To Make 不如 Sentences？

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, comparison

A 不如 B+object+verb+得+adjective
example:

> 玛丽不如保罗法语说得流利

A 不如 B+Verb-object+verb+得+adjective
example:

> 玛丽不如保罗说法语说得流利

Are these two patterns correct?

Some say it's correct, some says it's wrong, I'm so confused.

Can you please tell me the different patterns of using 不如 to make comparisons?

Comment: according to e。g。＂实用现代汉语语法＂
comparison A 不如 B， e。g。玛丽不如保罗 is a complete sentence with predicate 不如 meaning A 没有 B 好， can be followed by a phrase indicating in what respect A 没有 B 好，e。g。说法语说得流利 which also is a complete sentence （without subject），if the object 法语 is put before the verb 说 as is generally permissible  the result is 法语说得流利

Comment: maybe worth pointing out （１）说法语说得流利 and （２）法语说得流利 differ by more than position of 法语，in this respect note e。g。＂外国人实用汉语语法＂，程度补语，宾语的位置（１）要是动词谓语后面同时带宾语和程度补语，一定要重复动词，程度补语要放在重复的动词后边，助词＂得＂则要放在重复的动词和程度语之间，例如：回答问题回答得完整，打行李打得很结实，种树种得不多。It seems that by moving object 法语 in front of verb 说，length can be reduced by １ character。

Answer (score 3):

1. Both are correct.
2. Your question has nothing to do with `不如`. The point is `法语说得流利` vs `说法语说得流利`. The former's emphasis is `法语`, while the latter's one is `说法语`. Here's a nuance of the sentence's sense.

Answer (score 0):

The question here isn't too much about the 不如 pattern, but about 得.

When using 得 in the structure S + (V) + O + V + 得 + complement, you can drop the first verb. So both structures you used are right, whether using 不如 or not.

Answer (score 0):

usually people say the first one. But I don't think the second is wrong. I'm native speaker so I have no idea about the grammar. I can give examples. 我不如你有钱(I don't have as much money as you do)。我不如你。(you're better than me)。